# Present SFSafariViewController from not rootController swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios9, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have UINavigationController, firstViewController (rootController for navigationController), secondViewController and SFSafariViewController.

If I present SFSafariViewController from firstViewController, it shown correctly and load page successfully. But, if I move to secondViewController, and try to present SafariViewController, I see only white window.

I tried to present SFSafariViewController from:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
```

And I tried to present SFSafariViewController by touch on button and had same result.
The code for show SFSafariViewController:

```
let urlString:String = "https://google.com"
let url = NSURL(string:urlString)!
let svc = SFSafariViewController.init(URL: url)
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How do you present your _secondViewController_?

Comment: Matz, thank you, I found solution. I presented secondViewController by method presentViewController(..), but I must to use pushViewController(), really? When I set pushViewController it shown correctly

Comment: Yes, you can not present 2 Controller on top of each other. But I'm sure there was a notice in the console.

Comment: Unfortunately, I hadn't any notification about it in console, so I asked